# Retrieving S3 objects in parallel using boto3 ThreadPoolExecutor in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to figure out why the code below executes in the same time whether it's single threaded or using ThreadPoolExecutor. My Lambda function is retrieving multiple JSON files from S3, all of them roughly 2k in size. For my test I'm using 100 files, and it's taking 2+ seconds for this regardless of whether I use ThreadPoolExecutor or single threaded code. The number of worker threads doesn't make any difference either as I've tried 10 and 25 with the same result.

This is the multithreaded version:

```
    s3_data = {}
    logger.debug('Creating boto3 S3 client')
    # Make sure s3 client has a large enough connection pool
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3', config=botocore.config.Config(max_pool_connections=max_s3_threads))
    # This assumes boto3 clients are thread safe
    logger.debug(f'Starting parallel S3 data retrieval, max threads={max_s3_threads}')
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_s3_threads) as executor:
        s3_threads = {
            executor.submit(get_s3_data, s3_client, row['s3Key']): row['id']
            for row in rows.values() 
        }
        for s3_thread in concurrent.futures.as_completed(s3_threads):
            id = s3_threads[s3_thread]
            s3_data[ad_id] = s3_thread.result()
    logger.debug(f'Finished parallel S3 data retrieval, threads completed={len(s3_threads)}')
```

And this is the single threaded version:

```
    logger.debug('Starting sequential S3 data retrieval')
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    for row in unique_artworks.values():
        s3_data[row['artworkId']] = get_s3_data(s3_client, row['s3Key'])
    logger.debug(f'Finished sequential S3 data retrieval')
```

The `get_s3_data` function just calls `s3_client.get_object` with a bucket name it obtains from an environment variable and the key passed in and returns the JSON as a dict. Not very complicated.

This code should be I/O bound not CPU bound, so I don't think the GIL is getting in the way based on what I've read about it. The same S3 client object instance is used by all threads, but supposedly that is safe to do (I'm not seeing any wonky results in my output). I've tried creating the S3 client in the called function just in case, but that's even slower. I would expect to see some benefit from using ThreadPoolExecutor, but it's baffling me why I'm not.

Maybe there's something wrong in my code, or maybe there's some parameter somewhere I'm missing. I've Googled a ton of posts, blogs, and articles and still haven't hit on a solution, so I'm hoping someone here can provide some insight.